# sending data to viewcontroller shows nil data

Tags: parse-platform, swift2

for some reason i cannot get the Value to send to my AddParticipant View.

Here's the Data before "ValuetoPass" and after the segue:"LAbelText"

ValuetoPass =  GXEuoAkhjP
LabelText =

TableView Code for segue:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath        indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            //CODE TO BE RUN ON CELL TOUCH

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!;
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!;

    let valueToPass = self.participantId[indexPath.row] as String

    print("ValuetoPass = ",valueToPass)


   func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "editParticipant") {

            let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as!   AddViewController
            viewController.LabelText = valueToPass;        }

   }

}
```

Code for AddViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstnameTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastnameTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var gradeTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var teacherTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var phoneTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var transportationTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userSchoolTF: UITextField!


var LabelText = String()

@IBOutlet weak var qrCode: UIImageView!


@IBOutlet weak var userPicture: UIImageView!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    print("LabelText = ", LabelText)
    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    currentUser!.refreshInBackgroundWithBlock { (object, error) -> Void in
     //   print("Refreshed")
        currentUser!.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock { (result, error) -> Void in

            self.userSchoolTF.text = currentUser!.objectForKey("school") as? String
        }
    }
```

So I have the Data before it is sent, but it shows as nil after the segue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you created segue in Storyboard, am I right?
Put your prepareForSegue function out of tableView func. Also prepareForSegue should Override. Try using code below

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if( segue.identifier == "editParticipant" ){
        if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? AddViewController {
            destinationVC.LabelText = valueToPass
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed to what you have, was getting error because String was nil replaced var LabelText = String?() now my LabelText is showing as nil

Comment: It just started working, i knew i should of overrided it. Thank you ZassX

Answer (score 0):

Does Swift have NSString objects? Or is String the same thing?

In objective c, assigning to an object pointer is creating a reference to the previous object. When you make it weak, it doesn't add to the reference count, so if you deallocate the original pointer, you deallocate both. Strong means that it does add to the reference count, so deallocating the first will not actually deallocate the object.

If String and NSString are two different things, try making your type NSString instead, and see if it is retained.

I work in Obj-C, not Swift, and I'm not sure of the nuances between the two.

Comment: they are bridged so you can cast between them